# Adobe AIR: Is it possible to create a full screen app to fill multiple monitors?

Tags: macos, air, adobe, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

I am trying to build an Adobe AIR app that runs on two monitors with an extended desktop. Is that possible?

I've read fullscreen is restricted to a single display and the only option is to maximize the app to both displays. Is that right? If so, how can I hide OSX top menu bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, OSX does not allow you to have more than one full screen applications (of any kind, not just AIR) open at the same time nor it let's you to expand a full screen app to more than one display.

Answer (score 0):

An application window can span multiple displays as long as the window is sized properly. Menubar and dock can also be hidden. Check NSWindow in the apple documentation for more info. Adobe may or may not support this feature.

Comment: This was a question about the possibilities of Adobe Air.

Comment: We just used this technique with adobe air to span two monitors today.  We had to write a separate app to hide the menubar but it worked. Make sure you don't use fullscreen mode. Just size the air app to spawn both monitors.

Comment: The question was if it's possible to do **fullscreen** on **multiple monitors** with **Adobe Air**. And you replied suggesting the use of NSWindow which is not part of Adobe Air options. Thanks for the answer though. I'll remove the negative vote once voting again is unlocked as you're now offering a valid solution (using another app at the same time).

Comment: The system says I can't edit my vote unless you edit your answer.