# How to hide Mac OSX menu bar while running an Adobe AIR app?

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, air, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

I need to run an Adobe AIR app across 2 monitors, which cannot be done with fullscreen mode. I am wondering if there is a way to hide the the OSX (Mountain Lion) menu bar. I can span a chromeless AIR window across 2 monitors, but the OSX menu bar is always on top.

Someone posted that they were able to hide the OSX menu bar by using another app (in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174986/adobe-air-is-it-possible-to-create-a-full-screen-app-to-fill-multiple-monitors)), but so far I have not found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like they were using a Native application to remove the UI elements.

I'd suggest you look into doing this through an ANE. If you find the native code for this I'd be happy to wrap it into an ANE for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found an app that can hide the OSX menu bar on Mountain Lion, for AIR apps and pretty much any other apps.

The app is [MenuAndDockless](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/36314/menuanddockless)

Instructions:

1. Download the app, **install SIMBL loader first** (comes with the app download), then install MenuAndDockless app.
2. Start up the AIR app, or any other kind of app (you will need to restart it if it's already running). Go to the MenuAndDockless Settings (Menu > Window > Settings > Settings…)
3. Set the desired settings and restart your app.

Here's a detailed manual for the MenuAndDockless app: http://myownapp.com/manuals/mad_manual/